# C++ Type, Function, And Value Aliasing For Potentially Undefined Types

Tags: c++, c++11, cuda, sfinae

Suppose I have two libraries, let's arbitrarily call them "CUDA" and "HIP". These two libraries just so happen to have eerily similar interfaces, and I want to wrap these interfaces into a templated class where the template parameter defines which library is called. My current implementation is (in an abridged form):

```cpp
#define ALIAS_FUNCTION(Alias_,Original_)              \
  template <typename... Args> Alias_(Args&&... args)  \
  -> decltype(Original_(std::forward<Args>(args)...)) \
  { return Original_(std::forward<Args>(args)...); }

enum class Selector {CUDA,HIP};

template <Selector T> struct Interface;

#if (havecuda)
#  include <cuda_headers.h>
template <>
struct Interface<Selector::CUDA>
{
  using error_type = cudaError_t;
  static const auto success = cudaSuccess;

  ALIAS_FUNCTION(static constexpr getLastError,cudaGetLastError);
};
#endif

#if (havehip)
#  include <hip_headers.h>
template <>
struct Interface<Selector::HIP>
{
  using error_type = hipError_t;
  static const auto success = hipSuccess;

  ALIAS_FUNCTION(static constexpr getLastError,hipGetLastError);
};
#endif
```

While this *works* it is extremely painful to maintain, as I need to duplicate every alias, as well as make sure a fair chunk of boilerplate is correct. Not to mention the macros. What I want ideally is keep it all in one definition so something like:

```
template <Selector T>
struct Interface
{
  using error_type = std::conditional<T==Selector::CUDA,cudaError_t,hipError_t>;
  // do something similar to solve the function and variable aliasing
};
```

but alas `std::conditional` requires both types to be at least declared. Is there a cleverer solution here? It should ideally also be C++11.

edit: (just to answer the comments questions more visibly)
The idea of the `Interface` class is that there are other classes which derive from it (assuming one of `havecuda` or `havehip` or both is true) in order to gain access to the types:

```
template <Selector T>
class DoWork : Interface<T>
{
  using typename Interface<T>::error_type;
  using Interface<T>::success;
  using Interface<T>::getLastError;

  void work()
  {
    error_type err;
    if (getLastError() != success) {
      // something else
    }
  }
};

// instantiate the work classes if available
#if havecuda
template class DoWork<Selector::CUDA>;
#endif
#if havehip
template class DoWork<Selector::HIP>;
#endif
```

Comment: Does `std::conditional` actually need the types to be defined? Declarations might be sufficient.

Comment: A forward declare does suffice, but I have to also deal with the situation where either one of the other is neither defined nor declared. E.g. `havecuda = 1` and `havehip = 0`. In this case `std::conditional` breaks down...

Comment: Can both `havecuda` and `havehip` be true when compiling?

Comment: Yes, hence why I am using templates rather than pure macros. The idea is that there is a third class `DoWork<Selector T> : Interface<T>` that inherits the definitions a la `using Interface<T>::success`.

Answer (score 1):

How about forming an overload set of the different implementations? This solution does not even require a class template (although you can still add it back in, if you don't mind the additional boilerplate).

```
#define TAGGED_ALIAS_FUNCTION(Tag_, Alias_,Original_)            \
  template <typename... Args> auto Alias_(Tag_, Args&&... args)  \
  -> decltype(Original_(std::forward<Args>(args)...))            \
  { return Original_(std::forward<Args>(args)...);}

namespace Selector {
    struct CUDA {};
    struct HIP {};
}

#if (havecuda)
#include <cuda_headers.h>
  TAGGED_ALIAS_FUNCTION(Selector::CUDA, static constexpr getLastError,cudaGetLastError);
#endif

#if (havehip)
  TAGGED_ALIAS_FUNCTION(Selector::HIP, static constexpr getLastError,hipGetLastError);
#endif

template<typename Selector_T>
void myFunction()
{
   auto const last_error = getLastError(Selector_T{});
}
```

Comment: Hmmm the issue I see with this approach is that it is hard to stop people mixing the two libraries within the same set of calls. At least with classes you can somewhat enforce which types/functions are used by virtue of the class providing them itself. But I suspect these shortcomings are mostly down to the fact that what I want isn't possible yet in c++... :(